# Changing figure position from template

Tags: templates

I'm using this template in APA style: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-and-sample-for-authoring-apa7-manuscripts/pvhtwcrvcmsp

The template puts all figures at the end of the document. I'd rather have them where I declare them but I don't really know where I would even look for this. I checked the imported packages but I think you have to change this somewhere else. Where can I adjust this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Probably adding `floatsintext` to the documentclass options helps.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you linked to uses the `apa7` documentclass in combination with the `man` option.

In section "8 Dependencies"  of the apa7 manual we can find the following:

> `endfloat`: handles placing tables and figures at the end of a
> manuscript; used only with the `man` and `stu` options

which is the reason for the behaviour you observe.

Taking a look at section "4.1 Class options" of the apa7 manual we can find

> `floatsintext`: In `man` and `stu` mode, integrates floats (tables and
> figures) within the body of the text instead of postponing them until
> after the reference list.

Thus using `\documentclass[man, floatsintext]{apa7}` should result in the expected figure and table placement.